# Devise : Get full profile information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, linkedin-api, omniauth

I am trying to get information from full profile from a user , specifically all the past positions.

Here is the code in devise.rb:

```
  config.omniauth :linkedin, ENV["LINKEDIN_API_KEY"], ENV["LINKEDIN_SECRET_KEY"],
           :scope => 'r_fullprofile r_emailaddress r_network',
           :fields => %w(id email-address first-name last-name headline industry picture-url public-profile-url location connections three-current-positions three-past-positions recommendations-received honors-awards interests patents publications job-bookmarks)
```

I still am getting only the basic info , how do I get the past positions and other full profile information ?

These are the auth related gems in my gem file:

```
gem "linkedin"
gem "omniauth"
gem "omniauth-linkedin"
gem "omniauth-facebook"
gem "devise"
```

I am using Rails4

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm bumping into the same issue.

Comment: No. Haven't got a chance to look into it. Upvote the question so that it gets more attention.